# How do I get the filtered row count in Material UI X-Grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this XGrid:

```
<XGrid
  pageSize={pageSize}
  page={page}
  rowsPerPageOptions={[25, 50, 100]}
  rowCount={handleRowCount}
  onPageChange={onHandlePageChange}
  onPageSizeChange={onHandlePageSizeChange}
  rows={rows}
  columns={columns}
  paginationMode="server"
  pagination
  disableColumnResize={true}
  hideFooterSelectedRowCount={true}
/>
```

Whenever I apply a filter to the grid, the number of rows stays the same. I am writing a function to let the `rowCount` change dynamically, except I don't know how to get the count from the filtered rows. For instance, if I have 60 rows by default and I apply a filter to where there's 2 rows, then I want the grid to show 2 as the `rowCount`.

Here's a pseudocode of the function I'm trying to implement:

```
const handleRowCount = () => {
    if (filter) {
        rowCount = filteredRowCount; // I do not know how to get this value.
    } else {
        rowCount = serverRowCount;
    }
    return rowCount;
}
```

Is this the correct approach? I tried removing the `rowCount` prop, but the issues I am facing are that the filtering is still showing the total count of the rows from the backend and the grid doesn't go back to the first page. I tried changing the pagination to "client", but only the first page of rows shows.